# What do distributed frequency and raw frequency mean?

Tags: statistical-mt

What do distributed-frequency, distributed-frequency cum-age, raw-frequency, and raw-frequency-cum-range mean?

They are mentioned on [link](http://lbms03.cityu.edu.hk/theses/abt/phd-ctl-b42000269a.pdf):

**"Second, young age group under 15 rely more on core vocabulary than adults. For age group over 15 years old, core vocabulary occupies a stable ratio in their mental lexicon despite age increase. Each age group tends to acquire more core words selected on the basis of distributed-frequency-cum-age than those selected on the basis of raw frequency or raw-frequency-cum-range (e.g., Longman Defining Vocabulary, Oxford Defining Vocabulary, i.e. Oxford 3,000)".**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistical terminology.

Comment: I have asked on Cross Validated [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300510/what-is-the-difference-between-distributed-frequency-and-raw-frequency?noredirect=1#comment571228_300510) but there is no answer.

Comment: I'm voting to NOT close this question since it is clearly related to linguistics, here vocabulary. The statistics used here seem to be pretty specific to linguistics.

Comment: That said, a good way to answer the initial question would be to get the whole dissertation, which in all likelihood defines the measure you're asking about.

Comment: The terminology of disciplines other than linguistics is off-topic here. It is on-topic on discipline-specific sites (after you have applied enough diligence, e.g., looking up the terms in a dictionary or in wikipedia).

Comment: @jknappen I agree with you that non-linguistics questions are OT here. But this example looks like it is (or at least could be) specific to linguistics, hence belongs on a linguistics site.